# Respuesta de una función en una caja input

Tags: javascript, html, condiciones

¿Cómo puedo establecer la respuesta de la función *llamada `r`* dentro de una caja `input`? Pues, como lo tengo, lo escribe en un *HTML* aparte?

El valor del `input` es asignado a la variable `x1`.

Intenté colocar el resultado en la variable `res`, pero no me funcionó.

Este es mi código:

```
function r() {

    x1 = document.getElementById("txtExpression1").value;

    var expression1 = x1 >= 0 && x1 <= 90;
    var expression2 = x1 > 90 && x1 <= 180;
    var expression3 = x1 > 180 && x1 <= 270;
    var expression4 = x1 > 270 && x1 <= 360;
    var res;

    if (eval(expression1)) {
        res = document.write("Rumbo: N" + x1 + "E");
    } else if (eval(expression2)) {
        res = document.write("Rumbo: S" + x1 + " E");
    } else if (eval(expression3)) {
        res = document.write("Rumbo: S" + x1 + "W");
    } else if (eval(expression4)) {
        res = document.write("Rumbo: N" + x1 + "W");
    } else {
        res = document.write("No es un angulo valido");
    }
    document.getElementById("res").value = resultado
}
```

```html
<label for="txtExpression1"></label>
<p class="x1">X:
<input
    type="text"
    name="txtExpression1"
    id="txtExpression1"
    placeholder="Ingrese
    Coordenada X1"
></input></p>
<input
    type="button"
    onClick="r()"
    name="medio"
    id="medio"
    value="Punto medio"
> </input>
<label for="resultado"></label>
<input type="text" name="resultado" id="resultado"> </input>
```

Comment: `res="Rumbo: S"+x1+"W";` `document.getElementById("res").value = resultado`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas igualando la variable res al resultado de una funcion que es document.write(str); esa funcion imprime un string en el html el resultado que devuelva tal vez sea nulo o booleano, no estoy seguro, pero no te retorna el texto.. 
Lo que debes hacer es colocar el texto dentro de la variable de la siguiente manera.

```
function r(){

    x1=document.getElementById("txtExpression1").value;

var expression1 = x1>=0 && x1<=90;
var expression2 = x1>90 && x1<=180;
var expression3 = x1>180 && x1<=270;
var expression4 = x1>270 && x1<=360;
var res;

if (eval(expression1))
{
res="Rumbo: N"+x1+"E";
} else if (eval(expression2)){      
 res=("Rumbo: S"+x1+" E";
} else if (eval(expression3)){
 res="Rumbo: S"+x1+"W";    
} else if (eval(expression4)){
 res="Rumbo: N"+x1+"W";  
} else { 
 res=document.write("No es un angulo valido");
} 
document.getElementById("resultado").value = res;

}
```

Saludos, espero te sirva..

Comment: Muchas gracias el codigo corre perfecto

Comment: Genial amigo, de nada.